'gulp serve' keep getting stuck at 'configure-webpack'
I'm doing some SPFx developments. But today, all of sudden, whenever I run 'gulp serve', it only loads 1 time, and then in all the subsequent page refreshes, it keeps being stuck at:
[22:37:58] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
BAD!!: dist/87a74c23-4536-4aab-98bd-7df95142f163.manifest.json, RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Even cancelling the process takes about 5 mins every time. Then, I can never run my project in local anymore.
Note:
I've already tried below options:
rm -Rf node_modules
npm install
npm cache clean --force; gulp clean; gulp serve

But still see no difference. Please help.
